# Insert php com objeto como parâmetro

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Gostaria de entender como posso fazer uma função de inserção no php que usa um objeto como parâmetro. Exemplo:

```
class Aluno{
   private $nome;
   private $curso;
}

getters e setters...

public function insere(Aluno $aluno){
// suponho que aqui fica a definição dos atributos e o retorno do mysqli_query (não tenho certeza)

}
```

A minha dúvida é como eu posso fazer com que essa função possa inserir um registro no banco, quando ela simplesmente for chamada por um objeto instanciado. E gostaria que essa função não sofresse alterações no parâmetro, mesmo que se coloque mais atributos na classe. Preciso que sempre seja um objeto Aluno. Também gostaria de entender como posso usar o retorno dessa função.

Comment: Primeiro é importante que você relacione sua entidade aluno do banco(tabela) com sua classe Aluno. Depois é só efetuar o insert into normalmente, usando os getters para atribuir os valores das colunas da tabela.

Comment: Qual é realmente o problema ? É difícil perceber, qual é realmente o problema tendo este exemplo como base, e a tua explicação também não está clara ?

Comment: Edilson, eu disse acima que preciso entender como posso fazer uma função usando um objeto como parâmetro, eu não entendo exatamente como devo implementar a função, eu até coloquei um comentário supondo o que acredito que deve ser, mas não tenho certeza de como fazer.

Answer (score 1):

Olá, boa noite.
Sou iniciante em php, e também não utilizo o mysqli (estou utilizando [PDO](http://www.rafaelwendel.com/2011/12/tutorial-pdo-php-data-object/)),

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=nome_banco", "usuario_banco", "senha_banco");
$insert = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO NomeTabela (nome,curso) VALUES (:nome,:curso);");
$insert->bindValue(":nome",$aluno->nome);
$insert->bindValue(":curso",$aluno->curso);
$insert->execute();
```

Comment: Concaternar valores no SQL cria uma vulnerabilidade de segurança (SQL Injection). Imagina se alguém coloca como nome: 
"; DROP DATABASE; --

Comment: Olá, Obrigado pelo comentário, tinha respondido quando comecei os estudos em php/banco de dados. Fiz as modificações.